# WPF components don't update

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to run the Update function every 3s, which it does, but the view doesn't update.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Update);
        timer.Start();
    }

    void Update(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var stocks = new StockContentControl[] { A, B, C, D };
        foreach (var stock in stocks) 
            stock.Update();
    }

}

public class StockContentControl : ContentControl
{
    static readonly Random rnd = new Random();
    public StockContentControl() : base(){}

    private double _value;

    public double Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set { _value = value;}
    }

    public string ValueNormalized
    {
        get => Value.ToString("N2");
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        double change = rnd.NextDouble();
        Value += change;
    }

}
```

To bind in the Style Template, I use
`<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(local:StockContentControl.ValueNormalized), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>`
I tried to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged in the StockContentControl, but without any luck. When I use A.Update(), manually, in the MainWindow method, it works as expected.

Comment: You need to raise PropertyChanged event when you set the Value property.

Comment: You need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-5.0) interface and raise notifications from properties when they change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement  INotifyPropertyChanged in your  StockContentControl class and raise PropertyChanged event when a property changes.

```
public class StockContentControl : ContentControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    static readonly Random rnd = new Random();
    public StockContentControl() : base(){}

    private double _value;

    public double Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set 
       { 
          _value = value;
          NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
          NotifyPropertyChanged("ValueNormalized");
       }
    }

    public string ValueNormalized
    {
        get => Value.ToString("N2");
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        double change = rnd.NextDouble();
        Value += change;
    }

   private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
   {
      var handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null)
      {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: You also can use the nuget package "PropertyChanged.Fody" that does all the notify work for you. https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged